# How to match a submitted email domain with an array of domains and Insert it into a database? ASP CLASSIC

Tags: sql-server-2008, vba, asp-classic

I am struggling with the following problem in ASP classic.

I have created a form in ASP classic where multiple input fields must be given and on submission the input fields should be stored in a Microsoft SQL database.

One field however, the company, cant be stored immediately in the database table field. The company field in the database is of char type which represents the company, for example the company 'Apple' is equal to the field value D0001, 'Microsoft' is equal to D0002 and so on (don't ask me why this is done since a previous person did this and I cant change it).

In the form the person cant insert the company name since these names are default set and so are the code chars that are linked to them. To still get the right company names in the database I want to match the domain of a email to the right company (since email domains of a company are always the same and cant change).

Now I am perhaps a bit over my head but I was wondering what is the best way to do this? I was thinking about creating an array of all company's with their email domains and appointing the right chars to them. Then when a email is submitted I would check for the domain like so:

```
EmailDomain = len(request.Form("EMail")) - InStrRev(request.Form("EMail"),"@")
EmailDomain = Right(request.Form("EMail"),EmailDomain)
```

(For person@company.com this would result in company.com)

Then I would match the EmailDomain with the right company array (for example array(5) which was equal to comany.com)

The array value that was pointed to the right array (for example D0001) can then be transferred into a var and passed to the database query.

Though I don't know if this the proper way to do it since I am just thinking out loud. And besides that, I have no clue how I can make this array (in a foreach) to match the domain.. Is it even possible to create a array like Company[0] = company.com --> D0001 and how would I do this?

Some pointers would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) to map keys to values (i.e., email domains to company codes):

```vb
Dim CompanyByDomain
Set CompanyByDomain = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

CompanyByDomain.Add "microsoft.com", "D0001"
CompanyByDomain.Add "apple.com", "D0002"
' and so on, maybe you want to use a DB query and a loop to fill the dictionary
```

after the dictionary is built, you can use it like that:

```vb
Domain = LCase(SubstringAfter(Request.Form("EMail"), "@"))

If CompanyByDomain.Exists(Domain) Then
    CompanyCode = CompanyByDomain(Domain)
    ' insert record
Else
    ' show error
End If
```

where `SubstringAfter()` is a little helper function

```vb
Function SubstringAfter(str1, str2)
    Dim pos
    pos = InStr(str1, str2)
    If pos Then SubstringAfter = Mid(str1, pos + 1)
End Function
```

---

This is one of the ways to do it. Other ideas:

- query the company code from the DB directly in ASP instead of building a dictionary
- build an appropriate INSERT statement in SQL that fetches the company code from a related table and use that from ASP
- create a stored procedure that does all the work and necessary checks in SQL so that ASP has no own business logic and all it does is pass the form fields as parameters to the stored procedure

Comment: Excellent example and suggestions! Cheers!